# How to set a dual-boot installation with two hard drives (SSD and HDD)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, ssd

I'm about to format my PC with Windows 10 and I would like to install a system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu dual-boot. I have already done that in other occasions, but this time is different.

I don't know how to set my Linux partitions correctly so what I usually do is using the automatic tool in the Ubuntu installation process. It has worked for me over the past years whenever I tried to install Linux.

This time, my PC has a SSD (120 GB) and a HDD (1 TB), currently with Windows 10. I use the former to boot the system and store the most frequently used software, and the latter to store music, photos, videos, games, etc.

My intention is to **install both OS** so that they **both boot from the SSD** and have a minimum storage in it, while using the **HDD for storage in both OS**.

I will be using Ubuntu for programming, so I might not need as much space in the HDD. However, I will be using Windows for PC gaming, so I'll need more space there.

I don't mind deleting all my current data, since it's already backed up online. I would even prefer to delete all, since I want to clean my current Windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Windows normally on the SSD while leaving space for the Ubuntu installation. You can initialize the HDD here if you want.
2. Install Ubuntu with the "Install alongside Windows" option.
3. Make sure the BIOS' boot priority boots to the SSD before the HDD.

Since there's already an existing installation of Windows on the drive, the Ubuntu installer will give you an option to install alongside it.

Also, you can just install windows completely on the drive or use an existing windows install and Ubuntu can shrink the partition size, but I haven't tested this myself and usually shrink the partition from Windows.

Comment: Wouldn't that be installing each OS in separated disks? I want both OS to boot from SSD so that they can benefit from the booting speed that it provides, and also give both some space of the other disk for general use.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread your question. I'll change the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. And what would be a good set up of Linux partitions (/boot, /, /home, swap)? How many space each and in which disk?

Comment: Yeah, that would setup the partitions automatically, I think it maximizes the /home partition and gives ~20-30 GB for the / partition. If you want you can just use manual partitioning and create a single root partition and an optional swap partition.

Comment: A basic Linux installation only requires a root partition, really. A separate partition for /home, swap partition, etc are optional. Most installs separates /home because it allows easier migration to other distributions, etc.

Comment: Thanks for everything! I'll give it a try and come back with some results

Comment: Is this a hardware with Bios or Uefi?  That makes a difference.

Comment: Well, only on GRUB side but the windows install will create an ESP if it doesn't exist.

Comment: It is a hardware with BIOS